# How would I implement this type in Typescript (from Flow?)

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

I'd like to implement an equivalent in Typescript

`export type ObjMap<T> = { [key: string]: T, __proto__: null, ... }`

**Update**

To further clarify what this does, for an array of objects, it returns an array with a key added for each object in the source array. So:

```
const people = [
  { name: 'Bill', id: '1234' },
  { name: 'Sophie', id: '5309' }
]
```

would become

```
[
  { Bill: { name: 'Bill', id: '1234' },
  { Sophie: { name: 'Sophie', id: '5309' }
]
```

The `__proto__` is a way to ensure that the returned objects have no protoypes.

Comment: That kinda looks like it'd work...?

Comment: There's no direct support for exceptions to an index signature (although I see a lot of requests for this).  See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4896) and [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4896).

Comment: @jcalz Those two links are the same.

Comment: Okay, sorry, the other one was [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7765).